# Bounded imaginary part implies removable singularity at 0

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on the punctured unit disk. If the imaginary part of $f$ is bounded, is it true that $f$ has a removable singularity at 0?

I see that $|e^{-if}|=e^{Im\;f}$ so $e^{-if}$ is a bounded holomorphic function on the punctured unit disk and it follows that $e^{-if}$ has a removable singularity at 0. The problem is how to say the same for $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have observed that $g=e^{-if}$ is holomorphic on the open disk $D$. Therefore $g'=(-if')e^{-if}=-if'g$ is holomorphic on $D$. So $f'=ig'e^{if}$ is holomorphic on $D$. This implies that $f$ is holomorphic on $D$ (think of the Laurent series and its term by term derivative, for instance).

Comment: Let me see if I understand. So in the Laurent series of $f$ there cannot be terms with negative exponent for otherwise there will be such terms in the Laurent series of $f'$.

Comment: @learner Exactly. Like power series, you can differentiate Laurent series term by term. And the Lauren series expansions are unique. SO you get $f'$ holomorphic on one side. And the derivative of the Laurent series of $f$ on the other side. They are equal. So you see where the Laurent series came from. It could not have negative exponents in the first place.

Comment: If the real part of $f$ is bounded instead of the imaginary part, then it seems like the same argument works with $g=e^{f}$ and $f'=g'e^{-f}$. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, all the same.

Comment: If you differentiate the Laurent series term by term, what do you do at the $ z^0$ term? Is it possible for $f'$ to have no negative powers but for $f$ to have $1/z$ and no other negative powers?

Comment: @johnw. The $z^0=1$ term vanishes. And if there is $1/z$ in $f$, there will be $-1/z^2$ in $f'$.

Comment: @julien So the derivative of a function which is meromporphic will have residue zero everywhere?

Comment: @EricAuld I did not say that... or I don't understand your question, sorry.

Comment: @julien The way you describe to take the derivative of a Laurent series (get rid of the $z^0$ term, the $1/z$ term becomes $-1/z^2$) seems to imply that the coefficient of $1/z$ in the derivative will be zero.

Comment: @EricAuld Yes, it is true, as you can differentiate a Laurent series term-by-term.